# Where is the "Use proxy script" setting location in the registry? Script must disable this

Tags: powershell, proxy, registry

I created the code below to run as a scheduled task on logon.  Since the task has to run as the System user (deployed as GPO) the script identifies all users who have logged into the machine by SID, and runs the script for each user.  What this does is check if proxy is enabled, and disables it (we have an old version of Websense that randomly sets this value upon uninstall).  I also need to disable the "Use proxy script" setting (search proxy in Windows 10 you will see it as soon as you open the Proxy Settings).  I cannot find this registry value.  Can anyone help? (please restrict answers to the location of the registry setting, as it's the only solution I can use, and it would take pages to explain why).

```
$CheckFile = Test-Path c:\temp\logs\uninstall_websense.txt
if ($CheckFile)
{

$transcriptpath = "c:\temp\logs\uninstall_websense.txt"
Start-Transcript -Path $transcriptpath -Append

#
#
# Gathers SIDs from machine
##############################
$PatternSID = 'S-1-5-21-\d+-\d+\-\d+\-\d+$'
 Get-ItemProperty 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList\*' | Where-Object {$_.PSChildName -match $PatternSID} |
     select  @{name="SID";expression={$_.PSChildName}},
             @{name="Username";expression={$_.ProfileImagePath -replace '^(.*[\\\/])', ''}}

$SID =  Get-ItemProperty 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList\*' | Where-Object {$_.PSChildName -match $PatternSID} |
     select -Expandproperty PSChildName
Start-Sleep -s 3

#
# Creates HKEY_USERS drive
#############################
New-PSDrive HKU Registry HKEY_USERS
Set-Location HKU:
Start-Sleep -s 3

#
# Loops through SID array modifying registry value for each SID
##################################################################
$ErrorActionPreference = 'silentlycontinue'
Foreach ( $i in $SID )
{ 
Set-ItemProperty -Path "HKU:\$i\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings" -name ProxyServer -Value ""
Set-ItemProperty -Path "HKU:\$i\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings" -name ProxyEnable -Value 0
}

Write-Host "Proxy Status After Registry Change"
Write-Host "-------------------------------------------"
Foreach ( $i in $SID )
{ 
Get-ItemProperty -Path "HKU:\$i\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings" | Select-Object PSPath, ProxyServer, ProxyEnable        
}
Start-Sleep -s 3

#
# Launches Network Settings window (for some reason some versions Windows 10 require this for the setting to be applied)
###########################################################################################################################
start ms-settings:network-proxy
Start-Sleep -s 3
taskkill /F /IM SystemSettings.exe


Stop-Transcript
Rename-Item -Path "C:\temp\logs\uninstall_websense.txt" -NewName ("C:\temp\logs\$Env:COMPUTERNAME" + "_websense_uninstall.txt")
} else {
{exit}
}
```

Comment: You can discern any regkey setting, by firing up the MS SysInternals tools process explorer, registry monitor, etc., just by, open the GUI for the thingy you want to set, make the change and look at the SysInternals output, then copy and paste the registry key for your use case.

Comment: I have never done this before, thank you.